# Breaking a Loop With a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I'm creating a program for a game that clicks in random intervals for *X* seconds with *Y* time between each click.  Here is the code that does this.

```
    try {
        Util.autoCode rand = new Util.autoCode();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        int NoC;
        NoC = Integer.parseInt(this.numberOfClicksTF.getText().trim());

        if (NoC == 0) {
            while (NoC == 0) {
                // robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                System.out.println("Infinite Press");
                Thread.sleep(rand.clickDelay());
                System.out.println("Infinite Release");
                // robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                Thread.sleep(rand.interval());
                break;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < NoC; i++) {
                //robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                System.out.println("Click Press");
                Thread.sleep(rand.clickDelay());
                System.out.println("Click Release");
                // robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                Thread.sleep(rand.interval());
            }
        }

    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I commented out the mouse press and release just so I could do a check to make sure the timing was right, and that it would perform each click.  This code is started by JButton in a JFrame.  Whenever I press the start button, it starts the code and nothing but force closing it in Netbeans will stop it.  The goal is to have a start button initiate, and a stop button interrupt the code, but not close the JFrame.  I have been looking everywhere and haven't been able to find a straight answer.
Any help is welcomed and appreciated!

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep(..) on code executing from a listener. This will cause the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` to sleep and the GUI will no longer respond to events. Instead you should be using a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the event.

Answer (score 0):

You need tu use SwingWorker, for example:

in your JFrame you may have a SwingWorker and it "builder" method:

```
private SwingWorker worker;

private SwingWorker getWorker() {
    worker = worker == null ? worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("doInBackground!");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    } : worker;
    return worker;
}
```

now, in the swing main thread (used for visual components updates) you need to call the SwingWorker with your background task:

```
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (getWorker().getState().equals(SwingWorker.StateValue.STARTED)) {
        worker.cancel(true);
        worker = null;
    } else {
        getWorker().execute();
    }
}
```

You can click on the button as many times as you wish, the app will **create and run** a SwingWorker or kill and set to null the current SwingWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Literally ran into your exact same problem this week trying to make almost the same thing. First, let me suggest reading up on [multithreading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) in Java. It may seem complicated, but trust me it's necessary to understand why your program is not working. (I'll give a run down of what's happening below)

Essentially, your GUI is running on an Event Dispatcher Thread that needs to be separated from your robot. That is because when you call thread.sleep(), you essentially tell the GUI thread to sleep too, resulting in loss of GUI control. Start your robot and GUI in separate threads and have your JButtons invoke methods to get your robot thread to start and stop. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI();
            }
        });

}
```

To create your GUI(I don't know what your GUI is like, so I just wrote new GUI() to substitute for how you created yours), that way it's in the thread it's supposed to be in. Then in your eventListener, spawn a new thread holding the robot object everytime the start button is pressed:

```
if(actionEvent.getSource().equals(playButton)) { //listening for the play button
    if(robotThread == null) {
        autoClicker= new AutoClicker(); 
        Thread = new Thread(autoClicker);
        Thread.start();
    }
}
```

And initiate your robot object in the autoClicker() class like you did, and have autoClicker implement runnable.

```
public class AutoClicker implements Runnable{
    private Robot robot;

    public void run(){
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        //you need to learn about synchronization first
        while(true){
            synchronized(this){
                //do clicks and stuff here
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This way, your GUI and robots are in separate threads. In order to make JButtons start and stop your robot, you're going to need to learn synchronization to know how to properly multithread.

Another thing is that you should probably use the wait() method instead of sleep(), as sleep() would cause a lot more problems that's too much to go through in a single answer. Again, you need to learn concurrency/synchronization first.

If you want comment below and we can work out a way for me to DM you my code I'm working on right now, which is the exact same thing as you're trying to make. I can explain every part of it to you to help you on your way.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been away or else I would have responded sooner.  I have read through the multithreading post that you said I should read through.  I have a much better understanding of threading now, and the main problem I am facing is how to implement it.  Would you be able to DM me so that I could try to get a better understanding of the examples you posted?  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I'll admit it's a real bunch of spaghetti code so if you have questions you can comment here or create an "issue" on the github project and I should see it.